# How to have a flat appearance(No titlebar) with LWJGL in Java?

Tags: java, lwjgl, titlebar

I would like to know how to remove the titlebar in order to have a flat appearance in Java with LWJGL (and not a JFrame).

Example with titlebar:

[image]

Without titlebar:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DECORATED, GLFW_FALSE);
```

when initializing your window

Comment: np (: if you want to change back to the decorated window use glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DECORATED, GLFW_TRUE) (:

Comment: Okay ;) Thank’s ^^